# How do I call a jQuery function using a razor generated Id?

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a razor page that generates a table and I want to open a dialog box and insert a comment when a row image is clicked.  The table has 5 rows at this point.

Here is the revised code inside of the tbody tag:

```
  <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      string dropDownAccountName = "dropDownAccountsR" + CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3);
      string dropDownPayType = "dropDownPayTypesR" + CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3);
      string showComment = "showCommentR" + CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3);
      string openComment = "openCommentR" + CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3);
      string aComment = "aCommentR" + CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3);
      <tr style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-left: 5px; height: 14pt">
        <td id="commentContainer" align="center">
          <a id="@showComment" name="@showComment" class="showComment" href="#">
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/NotepadIcon.jpg")' height="20px" width="20px" style="border:none; text-decoration:none"
       alt="Add a Comment for this Account" /></a>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
          <select id="@dropDownAccountName" name="@dropDownAccountName" style="font-size:9pt; width:120px">
            @foreach (CasWtsUI.AccountTitle accountTitle in Model.Accounts)
            {
              <option value="@accountTitle.ID">@accountTitle.Title</option>
            }
          </select>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
          <select id="@dropDownPayType" name="@dropDownPayType" style="font-size:9pt; width:90px" >
            @foreach (CASCommon.PayType payType in Model.PayTypes)
            {
              <option value="@payType.ID">@payType.Type</option>
            }
          </select>
        </td>
        @for (int dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < inputDays; dayOffset++)
        {
          System.DateTime entryDate = firstDate.AddDays(dayOffset);
          string textBoxHours = "textBoxHoursR" +
            CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(@i.ToString(), 3) + "D" +
            CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(entryDate.Year.ToString(), 4) +
            CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(entryDate.Month.ToString(), 2) +
            CasWtsUI.Utility.PadWithZero(entryDate.Day.ToString(), 2);
          <td align="center" style="width: 70px; font-size: 9pt">
            @{string theDay = entryDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
              var backColor = "#ffffff"; }
            @if (theDay == "Saturday" || theDay == "Sunday")
            {
              backColor = "#f0f0f2";
            }
            <input type="text" id="@textBoxHours" name="@textBoxHours" style="width: 0.35in; background-color: @backColor"  />
          </td>
        }
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td id="@openComment" class="showComment" colspan="20" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 40px;
              width: 500px; display: none">
              Enter a Comment about this account:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input id="@aComment" name="@aComment" type="textbox" size="120" style="color:blue; background-color:#f0f0f2" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    }
  </tbody>
```

This is my click function

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showComment").click(function (e) {
      $('#openComment').toggle('fade');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you want to use id in function ? it is @showComment ? can you paste html which generated, btw, 1st of all use`$(".showComment").click(function (e) {` intead of `$("#showComment").click(function (e) {`

Comment: I made some changes in design, but still have the same issue.  Bill's suggestion helped in getting at least one occurrence to open, and that may have been my lack of information...thank you for your help and your patients.
I need to be able to use the jquery click function on the @openComment <td> tag

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you're trying to bind a click event to `#showComment`.  Looking at your HTML that's being rendered, the ids likely look like this: `#showCommentR001`, this is why your click event isn't firing.  Instead you'll want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $commentDialog = $("#Comment");
    $(".showComment").click(function() {
        $commentDialog.dialog("open");
    });

    $commentDialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "fadeIn",
        modal: true
    });
});​
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhayden1/8sgKX/) that should be similar to what's getting output in your view.

Comment: Is there anyone that can give me a hand on this issue.  I am trying to open a <td> tag with an id that is generated dynamically while building the table.  The id changes with each row.  I am trying to use jquery to display the correct <td> for making a comment regarding that particular row data.  I can't use the class as my identifier as Bill suggested, because it only opens the first occurrence of that class.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue.  You can grab the id of the a tag that's been clicked in the handler using this.id.  Look at the updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bhayden1/8sgKX/1/), does that help?